# Get rid of kth smallest and largest values of a dataset in SAS

Tags: dataset, sas

I have a datset sort of like this

obs| foo | bar | more

1  | 111 | 11 |  9
2  | 9   |  2  | 2
........

I need to throw out the 4 largest and 4 smallest of foo (later then I would do a similar thing with bar) basically to proceed but I'm unsure the most effective way to do this. I know there are functions smallest and largest but I don't understand how I can use them to get the smallest 4 or largest 4 from an already made dataset. I guess alternatively I could just remove the min and max 4 times but that sounds needlessly tedious/time consuming. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC RANK will do this for you pretty easily.  If you know the total count of observations, it's trivial - it's slightly harder if you don't.

```
proc rank data=sashelp.class out=class_ranks(where=(height_r>4 and weight_r>4));  
    ranks height_r weight_r;
    var height weight;
run;
```

That removes any observation that is in the 4 smallest heights or weights, for example.  The largest 4 would require knowing the maximum rank, or doing a second processing step.

```
data class_final;
  set class_ranks nobs=nobs;
  if height_r lt (nobs-3) and weight_r lt (nobs-3);
run;
```

Of course if you're just removing the values then do it all in the data step and `call missing` the variable if the condition is met rather than deleting the observation.

Comment: I had no idea that was the default behaviour for `proc rank` with no `groups=` option - thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to make at least 2 passes through your dataset however you do this - one to find out what the top and bottom 4 values are, and one to exclude those observations.

You can use proc univariate to get the top and bottom 5 values, and then use the output from that to create a where filter for a subsequent data step. Here's an example:

```
ods _all_ close;
ods output extremeobs = extremeobs;
proc univariate data = sashelp.cars;
    var MSRP INVOICE;
run;
ods listing;    

data _null_;
    do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.varname);
        set extremeobs;
        by varname notsorted;
        if _n_ = 2 then call symput(cats(varname,'_top4'),high);
        if _n_ = 4 then call symput(cats(varname,'_bottom4'),low);    
    end;
run;

data cars_filtered;
    set sashelp.cars(where = (      &MSRP_BOTTOM4 < MSRP < &MSRP_TOP4
                                and &INVOICE_BOTTOM4 < INVOICE < &INVOICE_TOP4
                             )
                    );
run;
```

If there are multiple observations that tie for 4th largest / smallest this will filter out all of them.

Comment: This is discussed in the [Proc Univariate documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect058.htm), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proc sql to place the number of distinct values of foo into a macro var (includes null values as distinct).

In you data step you can use first.foo and the macro var to selectively output only those that are no the smallest or largest 4 values.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select count(distinct foo) + count(distinct case when foo is null then 1 end)
    into :distinct_obs from have;
quit;

proc sort data = have; by foo; run;

data want;
    set have;
    by foo;
    if first.foo then count+1;
    if 4 < count < (&distinct_obs. - 3) then output;
    drop count;
run;
```

Comment: Full marks for creativity, but this isn't very efficient for larger datasets - it requires 2 sorts + 1 data step per variable filtered, which is the sort of iterative process the asker is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a way to do it that seems to work with IML (I'm practicing by trying to redo things different ways). I knew my maximum number of observations and had already sorted it by order of the variable of interest.

```
 PROC IML;
 EDIT data_set; 
 DELETE point {{1, 2, 3, 4,51, 52, 53, 54}; 
 PURGE;
 close data_set; 
 run;
```

I've not used IML very much but I stumbled upon this while reading documentation. Thank you to everyone who answered my question!